# Ruby не могу обновить gem htmlentities

Tags: ruby, heroku, redmine

Проблема следующая. Пытаюсь установить redmine на heroku.
Во время деполя вылазит ошибка:

```
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/htmlentities-4.3.1/lib/htmlentities/mappings/expanded.rb:465: warning: key "inodot" is duplicated and overwritten on line 466
```

Из за чего приложение не работает.
В проблеме разобрался, нужно удалить в файле лишнею строку или обновить гем до новой версии.
1) Обновить гем до новой версии не могу, так как есть зависимость, а ее изменить мне не удалось.

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "htmlentities":
  In Gemfile:
    htmlentities (~> 4.3.3)

    rbpdf (~> 1.18.7) x64-mingw32 was resolved to 1.18.7, which depends on
      htmlentities (= 4.3.1) x64-mingw32
```

2) Возможно подскажите как обновить сам гем файл внутри heroku ( при деплое гемы автоматически подгружает с https://rubygems.org/ ), т.е. что бы заработало приложение мне всего лишь нужно убрать одну строку в файле expanded.rb гема htmlentities.

Comment: `warning` это не ошибка, а предупреждение. Ошибка где-то ещё.

Answer (score 0):

Думал проблема в `warning` , но это действительно только предупреждение, после исправления посыпались другие ошибки из за несоответствий версий ruby с redmine. Текущий вопрос закрыт

Comment: Вы написали это ответом. Может, дополните вопрос с **реальным** сообщением об ошибке, и приведёте в ответе какие меры вы приняли?